# method boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

```
 if(response.isSuccessful())
               {
                   if(response.body().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("1")||response.body().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                   {


                       String message = response.body().getMessage();
                       // Snackbar.make(parentView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, DashBoard.class);
                       startActivity(i);
                       finish();
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_out_right);
                   }
                   else if(response.body().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                   {
                       String message = response.body().getMessage();
                       // Snackbar.make(parentView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }else {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.unexpected_response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }else {
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
```

Comment: paste your logcat please

Comment: Would be useful to know of what class type 'response' is as well.  Throw us a crumb.

Comment: probably ... `response.body().getSuccess()` returns null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your equal condition like this, And exception will be handled automatically

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(response.body().getSuccess()) || "2".equalsIgnoreCase(response.body().getSuccess())) {
            //do your work
        } else if ("0".equalsIgnoreCase(response.body().getSuccess())) {
            //do your work
        }else {
            //do your work
         // Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.unexpected_response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        //do your work
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `response.body().getSuccess()` returning `null` here .

**change your logic as.**

```
 if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getSuccess() != null)
               {
..
```

**Edits**

and as per Andy's answer

```
Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

also can cause exception in case of null.

Comment: Doesn't quite match error in title and the OP code is already guarded by isSuccessful.

Comment: @Andy ... ya but not with `response.body().getSuccess()` null value.

Answer (score 0):

This code executes when "not successful" which probably means you are passing a null to the toaster:

```
}else {
  Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```